# How to Send a Response Using Seneca and Express

Tags: node.js, express, microservices

I'm using Seneca to route API calls and express to serve my files.
The problem is I can't seem to find a way to send a response back to the client after getting my data from the API.
With express, I would just use `res.send`, but since I'm in the Seneca context I can't. Haven't found any reference to this issue in the documentation.

```
"use strict"; 
const bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const jsonp = require('jsonp-express');
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const path = require('path');
const seneca = require('seneca')();
const app = express();

module.exports = (function server( options ) {   

    seneca.add('role:api,cmd:getData', getData);

    seneca.act('role:web',{use:{
        prefix: '/api',
        pin: {role:'api',cmd:'*'},
        map:{
            getData: {GET:true}          // explicitly accepting GETs
        }
     }});

     app.use( seneca.export('web') )

     app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../dist/js')))
     app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../dist/public')))

     app.listen(3002, function () {
         console.log('listening on port 3002');
     });

    function getData(arg, done){
        //Getting data from somewhere....

        //Here I would like to send back a response to the client.            
     }
 }())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the 'web' related functionality is now moved into module 'seneca-web' along with separate adapter for express. I got the below modified version to work.

```
"use strict";

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const seneca = require('seneca')({ log: 'silent' });
const web = require('seneca-web');

let routes = [{
  prefix: '/api',
  pin: 'role:api,cmd:*',
  map: {
    getData: {
      GET: true
    }
  }
}];

let config = {
  context: app,
  routes: routes,
  adapter: require('seneca-web-adapter-express')
};

seneca.add('role:api,cmd:getData', getData);
seneca.use(web, config);

function getData(arg, done){
    done(null, {foo: 'bar'});
}

seneca.ready(() => {
  app.listen(3002, () => {
    console.log('listening on port 3002');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [senecajs documentation](https://github.com/senecajs/seneca-web#route-action-mapping), you *should* be able to just invoke `done()` within your `getData` method to return/send a value/response. Consider the following:

Here, I was able to hit `/api/getData` and receive `{foo: 'bar'}` the response.

```
"use strict"; 
const express = require('express');

const seneca = require('seneca')();
const app = express();

seneca.add('role:api,cmd:getData', getData);

seneca.act('role:web',{use:{
    prefix: '/api',
    pin: {role:'api',cmd:'*'},
    map:{
        getData: {GET:true}          // explicitly accepting GETs
    }
 }});

 app.use(seneca.export('web'));

 app.listen(3002, function () {
     console.log('listening on port 3002');
 });

function getData(arg, done){
    done(null, {foo: 'bar'});         
}
```

Comment: Works! It's way easier than expected.

Comment: hi, how come when I try to run this script of yours I get an error that says "app.use() requires middleware functions"?

Comment: same here, the seneca getting started ends up with the same error